# Convert .REG to .BAT using the command line

Tags: windows-registry, batch-file

I want to set this reg key in a bat-file:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\command]
```

> @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
>   00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\
>   6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\
>   00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,\
>   25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,\
>   00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,\
>   6f,00,74,00,6f,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
>   00,22,00,2c,00,20,00,49,00,6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,\
>   5f,00,46,00,75,00,6c,00,6c,00,73,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,25,\
>   00,31,00,00,00

I have tried do this:

```
reg add "HKCU\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\
6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\
00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,\
25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,\
00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,\
6f,00,74,00,6f,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
00,22,00,2c,00,20,00,49,00,6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,\
5f,00,46,00,75,00,6c,00,6c,00,73,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,25,\
00,31,00,00,00
```

but this won't work. Does someone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would use both a .reg and .bat file.

You can simply do:

```
reg import myfile.reg
```

and it will execute that .reg file without any popup such as "the registry entries have been added"

Given the location of the registry, make sure you run the batch file as Administrator.

Comment: thanks but i need use just a .bat (i will convert bat to exe)

Comment: Converting the bat to exe will still work, it just needs an .exe and .reg file then.

Comment: Okay, I'll express myself better,
I need a single file without reference to the external .reg,
cause this i use command line to do...

Comment: I don't think you have any choice here. You obviously need to put everything on one line, but given the length, commandline does not offer that much length for a single command. You could of course construct the .reg file from commandline, then import it, and then delete the .reg file again.

Comment: Thank's,
i think i have solved with this
put the hex value into this {" "},
i'll test.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the syntax for hex data is by using the `/d` parameter, for example :

```
reg add ... /d 00010000
```

See `reg add /?` for examples.